# Иерархическое отображение результатов mysql-запроса

Tags: mysql

Необходимо, чтобы результат запроса выглядел не так:

```
+------+------+-------+
| x    | y    | data  |
+------+------+-------+
|    3 |    3 |   172 |
|    3 |    3 |   721 |
|    3 |    3 |   652 |
|    3 |    3 |   444 |
|    3 |    3 |   781 |
|    2 |    2 |    48 |
|    2 |    2 |    27 |
|    2 |    2 |    13 |
|    2 |    2 |    16 |
|    2 |    2 |    99 |
|    4 |    4 |  4854 |
|    4 |    4 |  2723 |
|    4 |    4 |  1327 |
|    4 |    4 |  1663 |
|    4 |    4 |  9953 |
|    5 |    5 | 48545 |
|    5 |    5 | 27423 |
|    5 |    5 | 12327 |
|    5 |    5 | 16639 |
|    5 |    5 | 99530 |
|    1 |    1 |     4 |
|    1 |    1 |     7 |
|    1 |    1 |     3 |
|    1 |    1 |     6 |
|    1 |    1 |     9 |
+------+------+-------+
```

а так:

```
+------+------+-------+
| x    | y    | data  |
+------+------+-------+
|    3 |    3 |   172 |
|      |      |   721 |
|      |    4 |   652 |
|      |      |   444 |
|      |      |   781 |
|    2 |    2 |    48 |
|      |      |    27 |
|      |      |    13 |
|      |    3 |    16 |
|      |      |    99 |
|    4 |    4 |  4854 |
|      |      |  2723 |
|      |      |  1327 |
|      |    3 |  1663 |
|      |      |  9953 |
+------+------+-------+
```

Возможно ли это и если да, то как должен выглядеть запрос?

Comment: Такой результат должен быть в консоли? У Вам не кажется, что это извращение? Но думаю, что можно. Но изврат.

Comment: Нет, результат должен быть не в консоли - просто я так написал для лучшего понимая что мне нужно. Пишу прогу в Delphi, там делаю запрос, результат надо записать в Excel...

Comment: Копайте в сторону GROUP BY

Comment: А можно поконкретнее?

Comment: @glamcity тогда это даже не изврат. Если картинка с результатом -- это не реальный результат запроса, изображённого сверху, то -- вперёд. Читаете результат (что там -- recordset или что) по строкам, если x и/или y не совпадают с предыдущими значениями, то передаёте их в excel, а текущее значение меняете, если совпадают -- то не передаёте (или очищаете ячейку).

Comment: Ну такой вариант понятно как делать. Просто есть компонент TJvgExportExcel, который позволяет результат запроса напрямую передать в excel, без каких-либо дополнительных действий. Поэтому внешний вид надо реализовать в результате самого запроса...

Comment: Запрос имеет вид:
SELECT CONCAT(surname, " ", hunters.nm, " ", secnm) AS "ФИО", CONCAT(huntcard_serial, " ", huntcard_number, " ", huntcard_who) AS huntcard, CONCAT(period_start, " - ", period_end) AS period,',' places.nm AS place, animals.nm AS animal, closed FROM hunters, permission, permission_animals, animals, places',' WHERE permission_animals.id_animal=animals.id AND hunters.id=permission.id_hunter AND permission.id=permission_animals.id_permission AND place=places.id AND hunters.id='+IntToStr(user_report_id)

Вот только как убрать, например, повторяющиеся ФИО?

Comment: ?

     case when @fio = CONCAT(surname, " ", hunters.nm, " ", secnm) then '' else @fio := CONCAT(surname, " ", hunters.nm, " ", secnm) end as "ФИО"

Answer (score 1):

Вот для начального вопроса (если я его правильно понял):

```
select case when @x = x then ' ' else (@x := x) end x,
       case when @y = y then ' ' else (@y := y) end y,
       data 
from t join (select @x := NULL, @y := NULL) r;
```

(начальные 0 поменял на NULL)

**UPD**

Для данных из вопроса я сделал таблицу

```
create table t (x int, y int, data int);
```

занёс данные (чуть исправил, чтобы 'y' менялся. Выполнил запрос. Результаты показались удовлетворительными.

```
  (select @x := NULL, @y := NULL) r;
```

служит для задания начальных значений переменных `@x` и `@y`. Затем в запросе я сравниваю текущие значения поля со значением переменной, если совпадают, то результат NULL (сначала был пробел `' '`), не совпадают --  присваиваю переменной значение поля и выдаю его в результат

```
  case when @x = x then ' ' else (@x := x) end x
```

Сделать, чтобы отображался 'y' при смене 'x' пока не получилось.

**UPD2**

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT case when @fio = CONCAT(surname, " ", hunters.nm, " ", secnm) 
        then "" else @fio :=  CONCAT(surname, " ", hunters.nm, " ", secnm) end AS "ФИО",
        CONCAT(huntcard_serial, " ", huntcard_number, " ", huntcard_who) AS huntcard,
        CONCAT(period_start, " - ", period_end) AS period,
        ',' places.nm AS place,
        animals.nm AS animal, closed
    FROM hunters, permission,
        permission_animals, animals, places, (select @fio := NULL) r
    WHERE permission_animals.id_animal=animals.id
        AND hunters.id=permission.id_hunter
        AND permission.id=permission_animals.id_permission
        AND place=places.id AND hunters.id='+IntToStr(user_report_id)
```

Comment: По-моему, неправильно поняли. Мне надо, чтобы только не отображались одинаковые значения в столбцах...

Comment: Я Вас сейчас не понимаю. Одинаковые значения в столбцах x, y отображаются? (Ну с y может быть ситуация, когда меняется x, а у остаётся тем же самым). Если отображаются -- будем разбираться.

Да, вместо пробелов возможно больше подойдёт значение NULL, я этого TJvgExportExcel не знаю.

Comment: Не совсем понял что делать с этим запросом - в него вписывать свои таблицы и поля или как?

Comment: Подправил ответ

Comment: Подскажите, а как это будет выглядеть на моем примере?

Comment: Подправил ответ.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!!! Подскажите еще, почему CONCAT(huntcard_serial, " ", huntcard_number, " ", huntcard_who) AS huntcard возвращает пустую строку? (huntcard_serial - VARCHAR(5), huntcard_number - INT(10), huntcard_who - VARCHAR(256). huntcard_who - пустая строка)

Comment: Ну сегодня что-то с погодой, поэтому мои телепатические возможности сильно ограничены. Может быть huntcard_serial и huntcard_who -- пустые, а huntcard_number -- NULL. Такое бывает при OUTER JOIN, если строка в исходной таблице не найдена.